# display dropdownlist box option on jgrid

Tags: java, jquery

I have a drop down list box where i display timezone with gmt hours.
Now I want to display this option in Jgrid. Is it possible?

```
for(..)
{

<option value=<%=tzone.getTimeZoneID() %> > <%=tzone.getTimeZoneName() %>  </option>

}
```

In js file, i use

```
    var timeZone = $("#backDropDownTimezone").val();
```

hence only id is displayed but i want to display timezone name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var timeZone=$("#backDropDownTimezone").text()
```